# Python Paramiko - Determine what ciphers and key-exchange algorithms are available

Tags: python, encryption, ssh, paramiko

I have an automated SFTP program written in Python using the Paramiko library.  If I make a connection, I can show what ciphers and key exchange algorithms the transport is *using*.  However, I am not sure this is the same thing as the algorithms and ciphers that are *available*.

Example:

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh.load_system_host_keys()
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect("myhost.example.com", 22, username="xyzzy")
>>> t = ssh.get_transport()
>>> so = t.get_security_options()
>>> so.kex
('diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1')
>>> so.ciphers
('aes128-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'arcfour128', 'arcfour256')
```

Is this the same as what is *available*?  If not, is there any way to determine what is available programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`SecurityOptions` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.SecurityOptions) returned by the `Transport.get_security_options()` is:

> Simple object containing the security preferences of an ssh transport.
> These are tuples of acceptable ciphers, digests, key types, and key
> exchange algorithms, listed in order of preference.

So it lists ciphers and kex algorithms that the Paramiko library supports (or a subset that you have configured/allowed).

It is, what you (and Paramiko) are making *available* for the connection.

What is actually *used* in the end is the most preferred cipher/kex algorithm that is also supported (*available* in your terms) by the server.

---

To get list of supported algorithms, without connecting, you can use:

```
import paramiko
import socket

opts = paramiko.transport.Transport(socket.socket()).get_security_options()
print(opts.ciphers)
print(opts.kex)
```